# Looking up user Library folders on OSX from a bash script?

Tags: macos, bash

Apparently the *correct* way to find the place to store an application's data in OSX is to call in ObjectiveC

```
NSArray* theDirs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
    URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask]
```

Normally that would return `/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support`

How can I get that from bash script? Yes I know I could just do this

```
DIR="${HOME}/Library/Application Support"
```

But that's not really the correct way to do it. You're supposed to ask the OS so it can give you the actual directory. (might be on the network for example?).

Yes, I suppose I could write a small ObjectiveC app just to return that path but I'm assuming there's got to be a standard way to do this?

Comment: What about `set | grep DIR` to get a list of special directory settings from the environment. That may lead you to a way of finding a specific environment setting to use within a script? Linux makes use several DIR settings, but I haven't used OSX to compare how far it has strayed. I would also check for a config that holds the information that would allow you to capture that information by parsing/grepping the appropriate config.

Comment: Good idea but "Library/Application Support" doesn't show up in the output of `set` nor the output of `export` (the environment variables)

Comment: It was worth a shot. One of these days I'll have to try OSX (or whatever it is by then..)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is use [AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptx/concepts/work_with_as.html) and its [`System Events`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptx/concepts/as_related_apps.html) helper application.  [`osascript`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html) allows you to run AppleScript from the command line:

```
DIR="$(osascript \
      -e 'tell application "System Events"' \
      -e 'get POSIX path of (path to application support folder from user domain)' \
      -e 'end tell')"
echo $DIR

--> /Users/nad/Library/Application Support
```

Comment: It's not necessary to tell System Events; just the "get POSIX path" line will do.

Comment: This solution seems to process a dialog box asking for permission instead of silently providing the string for a bash script.