# mac os x: get localized path

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want to retrieve the localized name for a path on Mac OS X.
I cobbled together the code below from various sources.

My Mac is currently set to the French locale, set French as the primary language, rebooted, I reset the LANG environment variable in the terminal to fr_FR.UTF-8, but I cannot seem to get the localized path for the folder (e.g. /Users/bll/Music).  The locale seems to be working, the localized name does 
show up in the finder (Musique).

What am I missing here?

(I'm not a Mac programmer, not an objective-c programmer, don't speak french).

**Edit: Updated with current code, Info.plist file**

(I do understand the issues with display names with / characters embedded, just not going to worry about that at this time).

code:

```
#import "Foundation/NSObject.h"
#import "Foundation/NSFileManager.h"
#import "Foundation/NSProcessInfo.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <MacTypes.h>

int
main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  NSFileManager  *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
  NSString       *path = @"";;
  NSString       *npath = @"";
  NSArray        *npathcomp;
  NSUInteger     count;

  if (argc > 1) {
    NSArray *arguments = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments];
    path = arguments[1];
    npath = path;
    if (*argv[1] == '/') {
      npathcomp = [fm componentsToDisplayForPath:path];
      count = npathcomp.count - 1;
      npath = [[npathcomp subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange (1,count)] 
          componentsJoinedByString:@"/"];
    }
  }
  printf ("/%s\n", [npath UTF8String]);
  return 0;
}
```

Info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations</key>
  <true/>
  <key>CFBundleDictionaryVersion</key>
  <string>6.0</string>
  <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
  <string>localizeddirname</string>
  <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
  <string>localizeddirname</string>
  <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
  <string>Copyright 2017 Brad Lanam, Walnut Creek CA USA</string>
  <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
  <string>org.bdj.localizeddirname</string>
  <key>CFBundleName</key>
  <string>localizedirname</string>
  <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
  <string>APPL</string>
  <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
  <string>1.0.0</string>
  <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
  <string>10.6.0</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Compilation:

```
cp -p localizeddirname.plist Info.plist
clang \
-v \
    -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 \
    -framework Cocoa \
    -o localizeddirname \
    -Wl,-sectcreate,__TEXT,__info_plist,Info.plist \
    localizeddirname.m
rm -f Info.plist
```

Comment: If it can help, you can always access the music folder at `"/Users/bll/Music"` whatever the language the user sets (the translated name is only shown to the user for convenience, but the directory path is unchanged). See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28550564/4418092)

Comment: 'displayNameAtPath' returns the localized names for the languages your app supports. Compare the open dialogs of Xcode and TextEdit.

Comment: "...for the languages your app supports" : How do I change the program to indicate that it supports all languages?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the localized name is only appropriate for display to the user. You shouldn't use it for anything else.

Second, the display path is **not** the result of concatenating the display names for each item on the path. If you want the display path, you should use `-[NSFileManager componentsToDisplayForPath:]`. Note that this gives you an array of display components.

It is not appropriate to concatenate these with slash (/) characters to compose a pseudo-path. That's in part because display names can contain slashes, unlike Unix-level path components. (On disk, those will be stored as colons (:).) The display components should be displayed as separate components (like in a pop-up menu showing current location, an outline-type list, or an `NSPathControl`). If you must display the path in a single line, I'd separate the components with a graphical element, such as a right-pointing triangle image (or left-pointing for right-to-left languages).

To allow your tool to retrieve localized strings from the frameworks for locales it doesn't "support", you need to 1) embed an Info.plist into it in the `__TEXT,__info_plist` section; and 2) include the `CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations` key, mapped to boolean true. To embed the Info.plist file, use the compiler option `-Wl,-sectcreate,__TEXT,__info_plist,Info.plist`.

Comment: I have embedded an Info.plist file, but it is still not displaying the localized name.  This is a command line program, is there something else that needs to be done?

Comment: Edit your question to show the Info.plist file you're embedding. And might as well show your current code, while you're at it.

Comment: Updated the question with current code, Info.plist, compilation.

Comment: Huh. It's worked for me for other framework localized strings, but doesn't seem to work for this.

Comment: I guess this has to be re-written to open the proper NIB file and do all the lookups.  Or rewritten as a GUI program without a window (I have no clue on that, I'll try the first option).